Mint 21.3 did anyone installed Canon LBP2900 on this version
Seems that there's no one with this kind of hardware using Mint Cinamon 21.3.
Searched intensively threw the whole internet but, no luck.
There's a lot of examples with Ubuntu versions but, it simply doesn't work!
If there is something or someone who resolved problem with succesful installation of Canon LBP 2900 to Mint Cinamon 21.3 I would be very happy to find out.
Tried almost everything with this distro but no luck.
Succeeded only with Zorin OS 15.3 Education.
Unluckily Zorin OS 15.3 Education is insufficient distro for my needs so I can't keep it for a daily driver.
In case that someone succeeded to install Canon LBP 2900 to Mint Cinamon 21.3 please feel free to offer some steps how to do that..

this site is not a forum ... it is a Q&A site ... please ask about the problem, not about people's experience ... asking about experience is off topic here, because it is an opinion

My question is pretty obvious. In the other words: I need installation steps for setting up Canon LBP2900 on a Linux Cinamon 21.3 (edge) machine.

Mint 21.3 did anyone installed Canon LBP2900 on this version is not a question about the problem ... all answers are correct, therefore, opinions

If that's so, may'b You could be so kind to point out ONE correct answer - sollution (among other correct answers)..?

It's more likely that currently THERE IS NO CORRECT ANSWER FOR THE QUESTION:  HOW TO INSTALL CANON LBP2900 ON MINT CINAMON 21.3 SYSTEM?

You may think your question is obvious, but that does not mean we do not require it to be clearly stated, because what is obvious to one if often not obvious to another.  Second, we can be pretty sure you haven't actually "searched intensively threw (sp) the whole internet", and even if you had, that doesn't tell us anything. Please be precise, specific, and explicit in your question, in the details of what you have tried so far, etc. Please EDIT your post to fix these outstanding issues.

here`s the driver. What's the problem exactly? If you don't know how to download, extract and install .deb files then ask about THAT, succinctly and assertively. BTW, you're supposed to install the DEBIAN version of the driver that works for ALL Debian derivatives including Ubuntu and ALL it's derivatives, including unofficial ones like Mint or Zorin. That it worked with the latter and not the former is complete hogwash.

THERE IS NO CORRECT ANSWER FOR THE QUESTION: HOW TO INSTALL CANON LBP2900 ON MINT CINAMON 21.3 SYSTEM? ... no, there is no wrong answer for did anyone installed Canon LBP2900? ... and that is a problem at this site

Tried at first with that driver on the official Canon site but no luck.

Found some ppd files for that printer still, no luck. I want to point out that printer works perfectly on win10 and Zorin OS 15 for education.

The most intriguing fact is that the installation passes perfectly and the cup-s interface shows that everything is ok and ready for the printing. Even pop out messages are working while you make an attempt for test printing and informing you that printing is in process but - nothing's happening.

@ChanganAuto I already tried with that driver dozen of times but it's not functioning on Mint Cinamon 21.3. Actually those drivers are nonfunctional even on Zorin OS 15 for education I mentioned before!!  I had to use some alpha stage drivers of some russian programmer..

In short, I propose that we need to start thinking from the begining. Actually from my first 'question': Mint 21.3 did anyone installed Canon LBP2900 on this version? Looks familiar?

So, here's an advice for the future: Anything relevant should be in the question itself. This isn't a forum, it's a Q&A format and comments are allowed for us to ask for additional details or clarification, NOT for forum-style discussions. From the very start you've been told the same. A proper question should include everything you already tried and the results. Saying "tried everything, no luck", "doesn't work", etc. is a waste of time and a puerile rant. Instead you should have explained thing like "tried X drivers, correctly installed or with full error messages, tested this or that way

(...) with this result. This is how you formulate a question that can be properly answered. Fail to do this and, again, https://superuser.com/questions/1851379/mint-21-3-did-anyone-installed-canon-lbp2900-on-this-version?noredirect=1#comment2933160_1851379

Aparently, someone did had the same configuration and HELPED ME to get the CORRECT ANSWER TO MY QUESTION: Mint 21.3 did anyone installed Canon LBP2900 on this version. Actually the answer was :[https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=332788]

Mint 21.3 did anyone installed Canon LBP2900 on this version. Actually the answer was found here.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Welcome to Super User!
A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it. Add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.  See also, Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?.
